# Composite Primary Key and its Components

Tags: database, key, composite

There could be multiple candidate keys for a table and one of the candidate key can be used as Primary Key. If the primary key is composite key, means having multiple columns, what is the technical term for its component columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the relational model, the individual attributes of a compound candidate key (any or every candidate key) are just attributes. But in the context of normalization, attributes are either *prime* or *nonprime*. Prime attributes are a part of one or more candidate keys. Nonprime attributes are not part of any candidate key.

Apart from normalization, we usually don't talk about prime and nonprime attributes.